# Error when loading needs library for the first time

Tags: r, r-library

I installed the package "needs" in R and am trying to load it for the first time.

When loading it, I tried to agree when prompted that I want needs() to install and attach any package(s) that is needed when running a script. However, R throws an error. Can you please help?

```
> library(needs)
Should `needs` load itself when it's... needed?
  (this is recommended) 

1: No
2: Yes

Selection: 2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘needs’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'needs', details:
  call: file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w"))
  error: cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.4/etc/Rprofile.site': Permission denied
```

Comment: Did you try to restart your R session?

Comment: I did, a few times but it still is not working.